# Obtener parametro desde url en ASP.net core 2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, identity, knockoutjs

Tengo el siguiente metodo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este metodo lo que hace es enviarme un token de al correo para poder recuperar la contrasena y me funciona correctamente, ahora bien, cree la siguiente funcion con javascript para obtener el parametro que tengo en la url,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera puedo obtener el mismo parametro, que tengo en la url, que es la siguiente,

```
https://localhost:5001/AdminUsers/ResetPassword?token=CfDJ8KA%2FkcFChM9Bp%2F8oQHF0OBo113jwJ7upCuf31%2FnOQ%2BWnPS8Dl6kvAMvhRJ1wWsJEKvckfViPbczsNs09kmnUXcMtY7yxnePjossD3LwfVrJo1EXCRk%2B%2FyluiExuLziOmrtVrdMbVKUvn0oBti5vsF%2FOGs2yWdUR%2BFHrGQKe4ioVVnT9m6np0%2FhFjkZawi%2BvHqjM7ayP5cR5VQWTxrhjsvEzJctqsUhEudVXe53JAvmMW%2BYtGFKSSWwOTcp5RFDE9Hw%3D%3D
```

pero al momento que estoy intentando cambiar la contraseña con ese token, me indica que el token es invalido, pero el token es el mismo que el de la url, como les muestro en la siguiente imagen,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente mediante el action url envio el token, para poder cambiar la contraseña luego de eso retorno una vista con un formulario en el que el usuario tendra que introducir el usuario y la contraseña y esto lo recibo mediante un llamado ajax, ya que estoy utilizando como framework Knockout js, esto es lo que estoy haciendo, espero que me puedan ayudar,

Answer (score 0):

**Actualizacion:**

La unica diferencia entre ambos es que se reemplaza los caracteres `%2` por `/`. Por ejemplo:

```
CfDJ8KA%2
```

Se convierte en:

```
CfDJ8KA/
```

[Segun el estandar el caracteres `%2` o `%20` representa un espacio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) y los espacios no son validos en las url por lo que son reemplazados por `%2`.

Verifica si el generador de token, genera token con espacios y en caso de ser asi entonces tendras que reemplazar el caracter / por un espacio al momento de procesarlo en tu backend.

---

Respuesta original:

Mejor utiliza la clase [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) que fue diseñada específicamente para eso:

```
var query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
console.log(query.get("token")); // te imprimira el token
```

Comment: Utilice esa clase y me devuelve el token incorrecto como te especifique en la pregunta el token que me devuelve es este CfDJ8KA/kcFChM9Bp/8oQHF0OBo113jwJ7upCuf31/nOQ+WnPS8Dl6kvAMvhRJ1wWsJEKvckfViPbczsNs09kmnUXcMtY7yxne
PjossD3LwfVrJo1EXCRk+/yluiExuLziOmrtVrdMbVKUvn0oBti5vsF/OGs2yWdUR+FHrGQKe4ioVVnT9m6np0/hFjkZawi+vHqjM7
ayP5cR5VQWTxrhjsvEzJctqsUhEudVXe53JAvmMW+YtGFKSSWwOTcp5RFDE9Hw== y deberia ser el otro

Comment: Publica la url en la que estas probando

Comment: Publique la url en la respuesta

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Pero el incoveniente es que aveces me cambia estos caracteres por un %2F o %2B

Comment: Jose tienes que hacer un poco mas de esfuerzo. Si miras el link que te envie encontraras que el caracter `%2B` representa el simbolo `+`. Ahora tambien te tocara reemplazar ese valor por un + en el backend.

Comment: si y  lo hice ya estoy opteniendo el mismo parametro desde la url, pero por alguna razon me dice token invalid, editare la pregunta para que la veas

Answer (score -1):

La forma correcta seria enviar el token en el Authorization Request Header
[Enviar token en Authorization Header](https://zinoui.com/blog/ajax-basic-authentication)

Incluso es un standard en muchas tecnologias, no solo JS.
Este es un ejemplo usando JQuery, pero puedes encontrar ejemplos dependiendo el framework que quieras usar (Angualr, React, Vue, etc).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'service.svc/Request',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
    error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
  });
});

function setHeader(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'tu token, con espacios...');
}
```